# Firewall blocked some features of the program

Tags: windows, firewall

Hi I made a new build for my application. But I am getting an error when i am trying to open rox from that application, like firewall blocked some features of the program and after i clicked on do not show this message it is goes on freeze. When i check my earlier production version i am not getting any error like this and it is working fine.

Please help me. I am getting the same error when i tried to run application through the tool.

Comment: Flagged to move to superuser.

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to test if the firewall is blocking you.  Try connecting to the host and in question via Telnet

i.e.

```
telnet hostname.com 80
telnet hostname.com 1433
```

If you do not get an error and it takes you to a blank screen or returns output, you do not have a firewall issue

Comment: But I am not getting any error for previous version, we didnt change any code changes where we are getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

You have to allow the application to bypass your firewall every time it changes.

If the application changes in any way the firewall sees it as a new application.